# jQuery not returning meta, title from a string containing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HBMM5/9/) which contains a string containing html of whole page. I'm running jQuery to get its meta tag and title like this

```
> console.log( $body.find('meta[name=description]').html() );   
> //returns null 

> console.log( $body.find('title').length );             
> //returns 0
```

and its not happening. Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no wrapper element so you need to use filter

```
console.log($body.filter('meta').text())
```

Comment: @user3586217 jQuery seems to be converting your string to HTML by creating a `<div>` and setting the string as its innerHTML. `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` cannot reside within a `<div>`, so the browser ignores them and adds only their content instead, which means $body now has a bunch of text nodes and elements that you expect to reside within the ignored elements. `find` looks in the descendant elements of the current element group (so, within the text nodes and the descendants of `<head>`, for example, `<meta>` and `<title>` and since they do not have the elements you need, `find` fails.

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Normally a meta tag contains an attribute with content.
So the jQuery syntax would be this:

```
$html = $('<div>').html($body)
$('meta[name=description]', $html).attr('content')
```

When `$body` is equal `$(document)`, `$body.find('title').length` should equal to 1

Comment: The original poster is not asking about the current document, but about a new document generated from a string.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that after posting my answer. I updated the code.